# Fastest way to find Leading singular value and vector (power iteration, rsvd etc)

Tags: machine-learning, svd, matrix-decomposition

I want to know the fastest way to find out the leading singular value and vector of a large rectangular matrix. I have seen 2 suggestions and have questions on both of them :

1. Power Method : For this method, what is an appropriate stopping criteria?
2. Randomized SVD : I have tried to read the paper by Halko and it looks like all the theoretical results seems to be for k >= 2 (k is the number of singular values needed). I want to know if it is valid for k = 1 as well?